# Is there a way to _derive_ null rather than explicitly assigning it?

Tags: javascript, null

I've heard it bandied about that `null` is a *value* (loosely phrased) that has to be declared, that it cannot be derived by any means... I know that you can get `undefined` by something cheeky like `[][0]`. Is it true that there is no way to derive `null` in JavaScript?

Comment: `''.match(/./) === null`

Comment: But `match` is a function, and inside it is a literal `null`. I think OP wants a way to derive it without ever mentioning or using a function that mentions it.

Comment: @BoppreH: What do you mean by "*inside it is a literal `null`*"?

Comment: @BoppreH if nothing mentions something - it does not exist.

Comment: Actually @BoppreH `''.match(/./)` would work rather well... I'm after ways of deriving it... I never mentioned that you couldn't use a function or anything... I'm wondering about whether anything can be used to result in null... I've seen one answer below which contains the snippet mentioned by elclanrs and that works well too...

Comment: @Eliseod'Annunzio Oh. I thought this was a theoretical exercise. Maybe `eval("null")` (or derivations, like `"n" + "ull"`) fits your bill. If that's the case I think the question should be more clear.

Comment: @BoppreH Definitely not after anything like `eval("null")` or derivations thereof... I'm wondering about something that basically resolves as `null` without using a `null` literal...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many other expressions that return the `null` value as well, though using the `null` *literal* in your code is the simplest way. Here's a (rather exhaustive) collection of examples:

```
null
Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.prototype)
/[]/.exec("")
"".match(/[]/)
JSON.parse("null")
new Date(NaN).toJSON()
```